# Get the two numbers in a sorted list that are in range of input value

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function that given a sorted list of numbers and a random number `X`, will return a new array `[Y, Z]` such that `Y <= X < Z`. The function should also handle the edge cases where the input value is outside the range of all random numbers in the array.

This is what I have come up with:

```
const getRange = (ranges, value) => {
    let rangeTopIndex = ranges.findIndex(range => value < range);

    // The value must be larger than the max value in range,
    // use the last range.
    if (rangeTopIndex == -1) {
      rangeTopIndex = ranges.length - 1
    }

    // The value is smaller than the first value in range,
    // use the second value in range as "top" in range.
    if (rangeTopIndex == 0) {
      rangeTopIndex = 1;
    }

    // Bottom index is always the index before top.
    let rangeBottomIndex = rangeTopIndex - 1;
    return [ranges[rangeBottomIndex], ranges[rangeTopIndex]]
};
```

and these are the tests it should handle:

```
describe('getRange', function() {

  it('should get the correct range', () => {

    // In between two values
    expect(getRange([0, 0.2, 0.7, 1] , 0.5)).toEqual([0.2, 0.7]);
    expect(getRange([0, 0.2, 0.7, 1] , 0.1)).toEqual([0, 0.2]);
    expect(getRange([0, 0.2, 0.7, 1] , 0.2)).toEqual([0.2, 0.7]);

    // Edge cases
    expect(getRange([0, 0.2, 0.7, 1] , 0)).toEqual([0, 0.2]);
    expect(getRange([0, 0.2, 0.7, 1] , 1)).toEqual([0.7, 1]);

    // Outside boundary of range
    expect(getRange([0, 0.2, 0.7, 0.8] , 0.9)).toEqual([0.7, 0.8]);
    expect(getRange([0.2, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8] , 0.1)).toEqual([0.2, 0.3]);

    // Bonus if getRange can handle this (not necessary for my use case):
    // expect(getRange([0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.8] , 0.3)).toEqual([0.3, 0.3]);

  });
});
```

Given that performance really isn't an issue (`ranges` length will always be limited and this will not be performed in a hot path), **Is there a more elegant way to write this function?**

By elegant I mean something that uses less lines of code, and/or something more functional. If it could handle the "bonus" test above, that would also be great.

I get the feeling this could be done in a one-liner?

[Here is a](https://codepen.io/micnil/pen/NzWavX) CodePen snippet with jasmine tests.

**EDIT**: Woops, just saw that the bonus test had the wrong input value, making it completely illogical. It should be `expect(getRange([0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.8] , 0.3)).toEqual([0.3, 0.3]);`. Fixed above aswell.

Comment: are `Y` and `Z` adjacent values (in terms of indices) in the array?

Comment: @NinaScholz for what I gather `X` is not necessarily present in the array.

Comment: X doesn't need to be a value in the array. But Y and Z are adjecent values.

Comment: Why is your bonus case `[0.3, 0.3]` and not `[0.3, 0.8]` Your problem says `Y <= X < Z` not `Y <= X <= Z`

Comment: hmm.. your right @Mark_M. Guess my brain stopped working when I decided that this was a case that I wanted to avoid. With ```Y <= X < Z``` i meant in the "normal" case, but then the tests are what I want the function to actually handle. At this point, I am not sure that [..., 0.3, 0.3, ...] will be an issue though in my use case. Edit: The point is that all ranges (two consequetive values) should be *possible* to get as result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use recursion:

```
const getRange = ([a, b, ...xs], value) => 
  xs.length === 0 || value < b
    ? [a, b]
    : getRange([b, ...xs], value);
```

It works by comparing to the second element, and calling with the remained if it's too small.

I focused on passing the tests (let's call it "test-driven" ;) ), but there are some obvious edge cases you might want to cover (inputs shorter than 2 elements, for example)

Comment: ah nice! looks awesome. Good point with the inputs shorter than 2 elements. That would have hit me very soon. I'll hold off with marking as accepted for a little while in case someone else is working on an answer. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach, but with an edge case for

```
getRange([0, 0.2, 0.7, 1], 0.2));     // [0.2, 0.7]
```

which returns

```
[0, 0.2]
```

which is from the point of view with a delta for both values smaller than the given result.

```js
const
    getRange = (ranges, value) =>
        ranges.reduce((r, v) =>
            r.length < 2
                ? r.concat(v)
                : Math.abs(value - r[0]) >= Math.abs(value - v)
                    ? [r[r.length - 1], v]
                    : r
        , []);


// In between two values
console.log(getRange([0, 0.2, 0.7, 1], 0.5));     // [0.2, 0.7]
console.log(getRange([0, 0.2, 0.7, 1], 0.1));     // [0, 0.2]
console.log(getRange([0, 0.2, 0.7, 1], 0.2));     // [0.2, 0.7]

// Edge cases
console.log(getRange([0, 0.2, 0.7, 1], 0));       // [0, 0.2]
console.log(getRange([0, 0.2, 0.7, 1], 1));       // [0.7, 1]

// Outside boundary of range
console.log(getRange([0, 0.2, 0.7, 0.8], 0.9));   // [0.7, 0.8]
console.log(getRange([0.2, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8], 0.1)); // [0.2, 0.3]

// extra
console.log(getRange([0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.8], 0.3)); // [0.3, 0.3]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice solution! you made choosing an accepted answer difficult. I do think that user3297291 answer is cleaner, but I like how this one solves the issue with the bonus unit test. It's a bit weird how ranges sometimes are inclusive of the bottom value and sometimes it is not (see example [here](https://codepen.io/micnil/pen/Paoazb)). Although this is not an issue for my use case. Thank you Nina.